# How to modularize panels in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

Suppose I have the following layout for my page:

```
vertical panel mainbody = new VerticalPanel;

//beginning of 1st sub-vertical panel
VerticalPanel first_panel = new verticalPanel();
first_panel.add(...);
//other such stuff, end of first_panel
mainbody.add(first_panel);

//beginning of 2nd sub-vertical panel
VerticalPanel second_panel = new verticalPanel();
second_panel.add(...);
//other such stuff, end of first_panel
mainbody.add(second_panel);

//beginning of 3rd sub-vertical panel
VerticalPanel third_panel = new verticalPanel();
third_panel.add(...);
//other such stuff, end of first_panel
mainbody.add(third_panel);

//end of mainbody
RootPanel.get().add(mainbody);
```

I want to modularize it, such that each sub panel (`first_panel`, `second_panel` and `third_panel`) belong to individual files, so that after some import, I can just code this in the main page to do the trick:

```
vertical panel mainbody = new VerticalPanel;

mainbody.add(first_panel);
mainbody.add(second_panel);
mainbody.add(third_panel);

//end of mainbody
RootPanel.get().add(mainbody);
```

The sub-panels themselves may use other sub-panels, for which the modularization should cascade. Now what do I need to do to enable this? The Google documentation is not quite clear to me. Specifically,

1. How do I define those panels in individual files (packages or folders) so that they can be imported into the main file?
2. How do I import them (somewhat like `include` in PHP)?
3. What changes do I need to make to the `xml` file (if any is needed)?
4. How to define the same set of rules for the imported files also, so that the imports cascade? That is, if `a` imports `b`, and `b` imports `c` and `d` to construct itself, both `c` and `d` are imported into the main file dutring import?
5. Will the `CSS` rules in the main CSS file be enough for all imported panels?

If someone can explain this from the viewpoint of the default **StockWatcher** app which comes packaged with `GWT` (so that we can have some common ground for understanding the directory structure), it will be easy for me to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a `Widget` out of the panels.

```
package com.example.widgets // Make this package whatever you want

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite

public class FirstPanel extends Composite{

    private VerticalPanel verticalPanel;

    public FirstPanel(){

        verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();

        // All composites must call initWidget() in their constructors.
        initWidget(verticalPanel);

        // For your CSS
        setStyleName("example-SomeStyle");

        // Continue constructing object ...
    }

}
```

The `initWidget()` needs to be called exactly once every time the constructor is used. It sets the widget to be wrapped by the composite. Check the documentation [here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.html#initWidget%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget%29).

Then you'll be able to use it like so

```
VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();

FirstPanel firstPanel = new FirstPanel();
mainPanel.add(firstPanel);
```

1. The above should answer point 1
2. If your Widget isn't in the same package as the code above you'll need to import it. For the example above: `import com.example.widget.FirstPanel`
3. No changes need to be made in the XML file
4. Yes, the imports will cascade as you described.
5. The CSS Rule in the main CSS should be enough as long as you declare the style names in the widgets. You can do that by calling `setStyleName("example-SomeStyle");` as you can see in the example above.

Comment: One thing. I have developed everything based on panels. So now if I make widgets out of them, will any of the functionality defined for the panels (say, like event handlers like `click`, `mouseup`, etc) be disturbed?

Comment: By the way, I edited my 4th point, see if it is clear to you now..:)

Comment: And I didn't understand the directory structure. If you think of the StockWatcher app, there's package called `com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client` which itself contains 3 `java` files, `StockWatcher.java`, `GreetingService.java` and `GreetingServiceAsync.java`. Should I keep the component panels in this package, so that I can import it like `import com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.subpanel_1`?

Comment: Don't take it bad but I think you should start by learning Java, then only throw GWT into the mix. You're lacking some serious basic notions: you don't even know what a `package` is!

Comment: Well, you are right, I am pretty new to Java, and I have to do this GWT project simultaneously while learning Java. And I am new to GWT as well, so some questions may seem pretty basic, yes.

Comment: @Cupidvogel for the packaging you can put your panels in `com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.subpanels`, but then in StockWatcher.java you'll need to `import com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.subpanels.FirstPanel` and do so for each panel. The only time you don't need to import is when the class you want to use is in the exact same package than the file you are trying to use it in (I hope that wasn't too confusing).

Comment: Are these examples pertaining to UIBinder?

Comment: No, there are 2 ways to create the UI. The first is programmatic (my example) and the second is UIBinder. I didn't show an example of UIBinder because it's a little more complicated, but it's definitely worth taking a look at once you're more comfortable with Java. As Thomas Boyer said, you should really try to get a better understanding of Java before diving into GWT. It'll save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is called custom widgets. You can create a custom widget to represent first_panel, another one to represent second_panel, etc. Then you can make widgets that consist of other widgets, if necessary. Each custom widget is a separate class - it will be represented by a separate file (or two files if you use Ui:Binder for your custom widget).

You can read more about custom widgets here:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomWidgets